# Is there a way to invert the display of window border decorations?

Tags: gtk, window-decoration

All I can describe is that the result will be that the entire title bar will always be placed at the bottom of the window.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this but... Might be possible through Window Decorations in CompizConfig Settings Manager, though I've not been able to produce it myself.

Comment: Aww, I hope there's a way. =D I was curious of some of my sketches of windows, that the way the windows are displayed are like that :P

Answer (score 1):

With the window decorators available, this is not possible. There was some work under way to develop a new compiz decorator that would be able to do this, but as far as I can tell from the git tree of that project development seems to have stopped. Maybe some kind of box based window manager can do it, but I've never known any to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at Compiz, KDE, GTK, Ubuntu Tweak, Emerald and maybe others, I also cannot see that it is possible. Though I would love to be proven wrong.